# solr, how to search two type data?

Tags: solr

My application has tow type( or more) data, just like following:

1. name: nytimes news report, start_dt: 2013-09-13T
2. name: nytimes channel
3. name: nytimes news report, start_dt: 2013-09-10T

I want to order result if has field start_dt, so I my query is:

```
q=nytimes+AND+start_dt:[NOW+TO+NOW/DAY%2B2DAY]
```

but I want to get result of Number 1/2 above, what I will do?

------edit-------

I use sortMissingFirst with a bit more complex query:

```
<field name="start_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="false" sortMissingFirst='true'/>

q=(nytimes)+OR+(nytimes+AND+start_dt:[NOW+TO+NOW/DAY%2B2DAY])&sort=start_dt+asc
```

just I want.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort by start_date with the `sortMissingLast` option enabled on the field.
   This will cause all the results with blank start_date to be pushed at the end.
   You would lose the scoring however.
2. Boost on the basis of existence of the field `start_date:[* TO *]^10` (with edismax use `bq`) so that the results would be pushed up if the field has any value.

Comment: sortMissingLast  or last I will try it. but second I can't understand.

Comment: you can boost the documents depending upon the existence of the field which will push the results above if the value exists for start_date